# Optional @ViewBuilder closure

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is it possible in SwiftUI to have an optional `@ViewBuilder` closure? For example, let's say I want to develop a custom view that takes two view builder closures like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TopAndBottomView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    let topContent: () -> Content
    let bottomContent: () -> Content

    init(@ViewBuilder topContent: @escaping () -> Content, @ViewBuilder bottomContent: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.topContent = topContent
        self.bottomContent = bottomContent
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            topContent()
            Spacer()
            bottomContent()
        }
    }
}

struct TopAndBottomView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TopAndBottomView(topContent: {
            Text("TOP")
        }, bottomContent: {
            Text("BOTTOM")
        })
    }
}
```

But I'd like the bottom view to be optional. I tried with:

```
struct TopAndBottomView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    let topContent: () -> Content
    let bottomContent: (() -> Content)?

    init(@ViewBuilder topContent: @escaping () -> Content, @ViewBuilder bottomContent: (() -> Content)? = nil) {
        self.topContent = topContent
        self.bottomContent = bottomContent
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            topContent()
            Spacer()
            if bottomContent != nil {
                bottomContent!()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I get this error:

> Function builder attribute 'ViewBuilder' can only be applied to a
>   parameter of function type.

Thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Taking into account `buildIf` feature of `ViewBuilder` the following approach is possible that allows to keep `ViewBuilder` in `init` (that is preferable)

Tested & works with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2

```
struct TopAndBottomView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    let topContent: () -> Content
    let bottomContent: () -> Content?

    init(@ViewBuilder topContent: @escaping () -> Content, 
         @ViewBuilder bottomContent: @escaping () -> Content? = { nil }) {
        self.topContent = topContent
        self.bottomContent = bottomContent
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            topContent()
            Spacer()
            bottomContent()
        }
    }
}
```

So works as this one

```
struct TopAndBottomView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TopAndBottomView(topContent: {
            Text("TOP")
        }, bottomContent: {
            Text("BOTTOM")
        })
    }
}
```

and this one

```
struct TopAndBottomView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TopAndBottomView(topContent: {
            Text("TOP")
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you do this if the topContent and bottomContent are different view types? I made a new generic property but when using the default 'nil' argument, any callers can't infer the content type..

Comment: @JoeBayLD See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63636270/408142

Comment: This doesn't work as of Swift 5.7, Xcode 14. You need to use EmptyView() instead of nil/optional. So make it () -> ContentView = { EmptyView() }. Otherwise parent view cannot infer content type.

Comment: It is recommend to evaluate the escaping content closures in `init` rather than in `body` https://rensbr.eu/blog/swiftui-escaping-closures/

Answer (score 39):

@JoeBayLD asked:

> How would you do this if the topContent and bottomContent are different view types? I made a new generic property but when using the default 'nil' argument, any callers can't infer the content type

You can make both ViewBuilder parameters *non-optional*, and then handle the "no bottom content" case by making an extension `where BottomContent == EmptyView`:

```
struct TopAndBottomView<TopContent: View, BottomContent: View>: View {
    let topContent: TopContent
    let bottomContent: BottomContent

    init(@ViewBuilder topContent: () -> TopContent,
         @ViewBuilder bottomContent: () -> BottomContent) {
        self.topContent = topContent()
        self.bottomContent = bottomContent()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            topContent
            Spacer()
            bottomContent
        }
    }
}

extension TopAndBottomView where BottomContent == EmptyView {
    init(@ViewBuilder topContent: () -> TopContent) {
        self.init(topContent: topContent, bottomContent: { EmptyView() })
    }
}

// usage

TopAndBottomView(topContent: { Text("hello") })

TopAndBottomView(topContent: { Text("hello") }, bottomContent: { Text("world") })
```

Comment: That’s awesome - thanks! I’m not entirely sure why EmptyView is the same as no argument - but either way it works.

Comment: Great answer. A really nice utilization of extensions with where clauses. Using EmptyViews instead of Optionals is much more SwiftUI way to handle cases with no view. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In this fantastic [post](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/tips/optional-swiftui-views/) from Sundell, he suggests that we build a custom `struct` `Unwrap` to unwrap an optional value and turn it into a `View`, the following code is what he did in that post:

```
import SwiftUI

/// # Unwrap
/// unwraps a value (of type `Value`) and turns it 
/// into `some View` (== `Optional<Content>`).
struct Unwrap<Value, Content: View>: View {
    
    private let value  : Value?               // value to be unwrapped
    private let content: (Value) -> Content   // closure: turn `Value` into `Content`
    
    init(
        _ value: Value?,
         @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Value) -> Content  // ⭐️ @ViewBuilder
    ) {
        self.value   = value
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {   
        // map: (by the closure `content`)
        // nil (Optional<Value>.none)  -> nil (Optional<Content>.none)
        // Optional<Value>.some(Value) -> Optional<Content>.some(Content)
        value.map(content)  // Optional<Content>
    }
}
```

And then I wrote some code to demonstrate how we could use `Unwrap` to construct our views:

```
import SwiftUI

// MyView
struct MyView: View {
    
    @State private var isValue1Nil = false
    @State private var isValue2Nil = false
    
    var value1: Int? { isValue1Nil ? nil : 1}
    var value2: Int? { isValue2Nil ? nil : 2}
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            // stack of `Unwrap`s
            VStack {
                // ⭐️ `Unwrap` used here.
                Unwrap(value1) {
                    Color.red.overlay(Text("\($0)"))
                }
                Unwrap(value2) {
                    Color.orange.overlay(Text("\($0)"))
                }
            }.border(Color.blue, width: 3)
                
            // toggles
            HStack {
                Toggle(isOn: $isValue1Nil) {
                    Text("value1 is nil")
                }
                Toggle(isOn: $isValue2Nil) {
                    Text("value2 is nil")
                }
                Spacer()
            }
                .padding()
                .overlay(Rectangle().stroke(Color.gray, style: .init(dash: [6])))
                
        } // VStack (container)
            .padding()
            .border(Color.gray, width: 3)
    }
}
```

And the result is as follows:

[image: optional views]

----[ edited ]----

Or alternatively, we can make a `View` extension to do the job:

```
// view.ifLet(_:then:)
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder func ifLet<Value, Content: View>(
        _ value: Value?, 
        @ViewBuilder then modifySelfWithValue: (Self, Value) -> Content 
    ) -> some View {
        if value != nil {
            modifySelfWithValue(self, value!)
        } else { self }
    }
}
```

The following is another demo on how to use this extension:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isNil = false
    var value: Int? { isNil ? nil : 2 }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Color.red.overlay(Text("1"))
                // ⭐️ view.ifLet(_:then:)
                .ifLet(value) { (thisView, value) in
                    // construct new view with `thisView` and `value`
                    VStack {
                        thisView
                        Color.orange.overlay(Text("\(value)"))
                    }
            } // view modified by `ifLet`
                .border(Color.blue, width: 3)
                
            // toggles
            Toggle(isOn: $isNil) { Text("value is nil") }
                .padding()
                .overlay(Rectangle().stroke(Color.gray, style: .init(dash: [6])))
            
        } // VStack (container)
            .padding()
            .border(Color.gray, width: 3).frame(height: 300)
    }
}
```

and the result is:

[image: optional view]

Comment: This is not what the question is about at all. Did you even read it?

Answer (score 3):

Set the default value for @ViewBuilder View, in order to achieve what you're looking for:

```
struct AlertView<InputFields: View, Actions: View>: View {
    private let inputFields: InputFields
    private let actions: Actions

    init(
        @ViewBuilder inputFields: () -> InputFields = { EmptyView() }, <=== HERE
        @ViewBuilder actions: () -> Actions = { EmptyView() } <=== HERE
    ) {
        self.inputFields = inputFields()
        self.actions = actions()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            inputFields
            actions
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is **NOT** what the OP was looking for. In your solution `actions` and `inputFields` are not view builders.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an optional @ViewBuilder parameter, a workaround is to set the default value of the parameter to EmptyView(). While this is not possible directly in the SwiftUI view struct, we can add an extension with an `init()` as follows:

```
/// View with mandatory icon view builder.
struct Hint<IconView: View>: View {
    var message: String
    @ViewBuilder var icon: IconView

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            icon.frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            Text(message)
        }
    }
}

/// View Extensions that sets the icon view builder default to EmptyView().
extension Hint<EmptyView> {
    init(message: String) {
        self.message = message
        self.icon = EmptyView()
    }
}
```

Like this you can use the Hint-View either by including the icon view builder or by leaving it out (in which case the default EmptyView is used):

```
Hint(message: "This is a warning with icon!", icon: { Image(systemName: .exclamationmarkTriangle) })
Hint(message: "This is a warning with icon!")
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you dont need the @ViewBuilder in your initializer so this would work:

```
struct TopAndBottomView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    let topContent: () -> Content
    let bottomContent: (() -> Content)?

    init(@ViewBuilder topContent: @escaping () -> Content, bottomContent: (() -> Content)? = nil) {
        self.topContent = topContent
        self.bottomContent = bottomContent
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            topContent()
            Spacer()
            
            if bottomContent != nil {
                bottomContent!()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And how to use:

```swift
TopAndBottomView(topContent: {
    Text("top")
})
 
TopAndBottomView(topContent: {
    Text("top")
}, bottomContent: {
    Text("optional bottom")
})
```